# Jquery find all ids starting with a string?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Just wondered how I would search for all the ids starting with "content_" in the whole page and also a way to only find them in a named div called "extra_content". Once i have all the ids i want to hide them.

Below is an example of what i want to find.

```
<div id="content_1"></div> <-- Find
<div id="content_2"></div> <-- Find
<div id="contet_3"></div>

<div id="extra_content"> 
    <div id="content_extra_1"></div> <-- Find
    <div id="content_extra_2"></div> < -- Find
</div>
```

Examples would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: do you want to hide all or get the ids?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Use the [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('[id^="content_"]').hide();
```

To limit the search to elements within `extra_content`:

```
$('#extra_content [id^="content_"]').hide();
```

Comment: I didn't know the attribute-starts-with selector (+1 for that to both of you) but I think you should add an attribute class to manipulate that instead of using the id attribute. It's more easy to understand, more clean and it helps to prevent bugs...

Comment: Hi, I have a confusion, I have a scenario like this : 
    `<div id="min1"></div>`
   `<div id="max1"></div>` 
      
    `<div id="min2"></div> `
   ` <div id="max2"></div> `
. I am using this : `$("[id^=min]", "[id^=max]").val('hello')` to do something with them. It doesn't work. What is the problem ?

Comment: @MazharMIK The problem you have is in your separating the selectors. It should be: `$("[id^=min],[id^=max]").val('hello')` . in this case. (P.S Classes are your friend)