# How can i use starts with in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a HTMl as shown below

```
<div id="ordersdiv">
   <div id="addtoordersdiv68">
   </div>

   <div id="addtoordersdiv67">
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to get all the numbers that starts with `addtoordersdiv`  within an array

Could anybody please tell me how can i find out `startswith` in jQuery ??

Comment: Can you amend the HTML? If so, put the index value in a data attribute, and use `map` to create the array of them. It will be much faster than the 'attribute starts with' selector.

Comment: Refer an [Old Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616826/jquery-find-all-ids-starting-with-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var numbers = $('#ordersdiv').children('[id^=addtoordersdiv]').map(function() {
   return this.id.replace('addtoordersdiv', '');
}).get();
```

Comment: Thank you very  much , 
console.log(typeof(numbers));  , I get as Object , how can i make that to array instead of Object ?? Could you please tell me

Comment: @PreethiJain You are welcome, the returned value is an array and arrays are object.

Answer (score 1):

[Start with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('div[id^=addtoordersdiv]')
```

Comment: So can i use directly as $('div[id^=addtoordersdiv]').each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});

Comment: But when i tried i am getting 0 and 1 in console .

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
<script>
  $( div[id^='addtoordersdiv'] )./**Operations*/
  .
  .
  .
</script>
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following that uses [jQuery's `.map()` function](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

```
var arr = $("[id^=addtoordersdiv]").map(function() {
    var idStripped = $(this).attr("id").replace("addtoordersdiv", "")
    return parseInt(idStripped);
});
console.log("Your array is", arr);
```

You're better off putting the number in a data attribute though, for example:

```
<div id="ordersdiv">
   <div class="addtoordersdiv" data-order-num="68">
   </div>

   <div class="addtoordersdiv" data-order-num="67">
   </div>
</div>
```

That way you're not relying on parsing an in to get the number. Also, I'd recommend using camel casing or dashes to make your classes/ids more readable, e.g. `add-to-orders` and not including 'div' in the class name. That way, if you refactor to use an unordered list, your classes still make sense. E.g.:

```
<ul id="orders">
   <li class="order" data-order-num="68">
   </li>
   <li class="order" data-order-num="67">
   </li>
</ul>
```