# JQuery: Find all ids starting with any one of the specified Strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I understand that I can use below selector to select a div starting with one string.

```
$('[id^="content_"]')
```

[Find All Ids starting with a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616826/jquery-find-all-ids-starting-with-content)

I have Divs that starts with Strings "content_" or "list_".
How do I select all divs on my document that starts with one of above 2 strings? 
Something like below that should work,

```
$('[id^="content_"] OR [id^="content_"]')
```

Comment: If you need to select multiple elements, why not apply class for them?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use comma separated list of jquery selectors

```
$('[id^="content_"],[id^="list_"]')
```

Comment: one up for giving before me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use comma to have multiple selectors. It will consider both

```js
$('[id^=content_],[id^=list_]').each(function(){

   alert($(this).text());
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="anchor">Shoaib</div>
<div id="content_anchor">Sajeed</div>
<div id="list_anchor">Chikate</div>
```