# jQuery: Can I specify multiple ID's in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script for a slider called Slicebox, and in order for me to have two different sizes of images for mobile and desktop size, I need to have 2 copies of the same feature on my website.

It's inconvenient but I like the slider so I want to see if I can make this work more efficiently...

Instead of having two, almost identical, copies of the same script in my footer... I only have 3 lines that are different and I want to see if I can merge them.

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var Page = (function() {
            var $navArrows = $( "#nav-arrows-sm" ).hide(),
                $navDots = $( "#nav-dots-sm" ).hide(),
                $nav = $navDots.children( "span" ),
                $navFirst = $navDots.children( "span:first-child" ),
                slicebox = $( "#sb-slider-sm" ).slicebox( {
                    onReady : function() {
                        $navArrows.show();
                        $navDots.show();
                        $navFirst.addClass( "nav-dot-current" );
                    },
                    onBeforeChange : function( pos ) {
                        $nav.removeClass( "nav-dot-current" );
                        $nav.eq( pos ).addClass( "nav-dot-current" );
                    },
                    colorHiddenSides : "#444",
                    autoplay : true,
                    interval: 7000,
                    easing : "ease",
                    disperseFactor : 30
                } ),
                init = function() {
                    initEvents();
                },
                initEvents = function() {
                    $navArrows.children( ":first" ).on( "click", function() {
                        slicebox.next();
                        return false;
                    } );
                    $navArrows.children( ":last" ).on( "click", function() {
                        slicebox.previous();
                        return false;
                    } );
                    $nav.each( function( i ) {
                        $( this ).on( "click", function( event ) {
                            var $dot = $( this );
                            if( !slicebox.isActive() ) {
                                $nav.removeClass( "nav-dot-current" );
                                $dot.addClass( "nav-dot-current" );
                            }
                            slicebox.jump( i + 1 );
                            return false;
                        } );
                    } );
                };
                return { init : init };
        })();
        Page.init();
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var Page = (function() {
            var $navArrows = $( "#nav-arrows-lg" ).hide(),
                $navDots = $( "#nav-dots-lg" ).hide(),
                $nav = $navDots.children( "span" ),
                $navFirst = $navDots.children( "span:first-child" ),
                slicebox = $( "#sb-slider-lg" ).slicebox( {
                    onReady : function() {
                        $navArrows.show();
                        $navDots.show();
                        $navFirst.addClass( "nav-dot-current" );
                    },
                    onBeforeChange : function( pos ) {
                        $nav.removeClass( "nav-dot-current" );
                        $nav.eq( pos ).addClass( "nav-dot-current" );
                    },
                    colorHiddenSides : "#444",
                    autoplay : true,
                    interval: 7000,
                    easing : "ease",
                    disperseFactor : 30
                } ),
                init = function() {
                    initEvents();
                },
                initEvents = function() {
                    $navArrows.children( ":first" ).on( "click", function() {
                        slicebox.next();
                        return false;
                    } );
                    $navArrows.children( ":last" ).on( "click", function() {
                        slicebox.previous();
                        return false;
                    } );
                    $nav.each( function( i ) {
                        $( this ).on( "click", function( event ) {
                            var $dot = $( this );
                            if( !slicebox.isActive() ) {
                                $nav.removeClass( "nav-dot-current" );
                                $dot.addClass( "nav-dot-current" );
                            }
                            slicebox.jump( i + 1 );
                            return false;
                        } );
                    } );
                };
                return { init : init };
        })();
        Page.init();
    });
</script>
```

At the very top there is this chunk of code:

```
            var $navArrows = $( "#nav-arrows-lg" ).hide(),
                $navDots = $( "#nav-dots-lg" ).hide(),
                $nav = $navDots.children( "span" ),
                $navFirst = $navDots.children( "span:first-child" ),
                slicebox = $( "#sb-slider-lg" ).slicebox( {
```

There are three ID's:

```
 #nav-arrows-lg
 #nav-dots-lg
 #nav-slider-lg
```

Now I have the same with `-sm` instead of `-lg`, and I want to know if I can do something like this:

```
            var $navArrows = $( "#nav-arrows-sm" + "#nav-arrows-lg" ).hide(),
                $navDots = $( "#nav-dots-sm" + "#nav-dots-lg" ).hide(),
                $nav = $navDots.children( "span" ),
                $navFirst = $navDots.children( "span:first-child" ),
                slicebox = $( "#sb-slider-sm" + "#sb-slider-lg" ).slicebox( {
```

**Is there a way for the variable to include both of those ID's?**

---

I just tried doing this:
I'm not sure how to get this working, it could just be the way the script is written -- it may not be able to handle this. I'm not sure.

```
                            var navArrowsList = "#nav-arrows-sm," + "#nav-arrows-lg";
                            var navDotsList = "#nav-dots-sm," + "#nav-dots-lg";
                            var navSliderList = "#sb-slider-sm," + "#sb-slider-lg";
                            var $navArrows = $(navArrowsList).hide(),
                                $navDots = $(navDotsList).hide(),
                                $nav = $navDots.children( "span" ),
                                $navFirst = $navDots.children( "span:first-child" ),
                                slicebox = $(navSliderList).slicebox( {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to combine two or more selector.

```
var $navArrows = $( "#nav-arrows-sm, #nav-arrows-lg" ).hide();
```

> You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single
>   result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to
>   select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the
>   returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in
>   document order. An alternative to this combinator is the .add()
>   method.

Comment: None of this seems to be working for me, I can't figure it out, but I may move to a more efficient slider that's more CSS than anything... all I really am trying to do is allow the image sizes to be changed on media width less than and more than 40em (641px)

Comment: Can you make a brief fiddle with related html and javascript and let me know what is problem with that

Comment: I can't get it to work in jsfiddle, any way if you wanna mess around with it this is the demo url for the plugin http://tympanus.net/Development/Slicebox/ and the site that I'm messing with right now is http://mrobertsdesign.ca -- you'll see it right there at the homepage, you can inspect element and change the script at the bottom of the page to see what I'm talking about!

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as correct because it should technically work... you did answer my question. Just can't get it to work with the script.

Comment: I can try to help you if you make brief fiddle and explain that you want in that fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

I think @Adil's answer might be the best here, as he mentioned you can use multiple id selectors which only requires you to update your code in a couple of places.

However, you could also use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
which I totally ganked from @Box9 on this post([Jquery find all ids starting with a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616826/jquery-find-all-ids-starting-with-content)).

In your case it would look like: `$('[id^="nav-arrows_"]').hide();`

Comment: This is actually really cool, I don't think I'm going to be able to get this to work though unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

As @Adil answered,

```
var $navArrows = $( "#nav-arrows-sm, #nav-arrows-lg" ).hide();
```

or You can create your Variable to hold this IDs in it. Something like this.

```
var idList = "#nav-arrows-sm," + "#nav-arrows-lg," + "#SelectorN";
```

and use this variable in your code, but this is not an Optimized way, you need a Loop to get those all IDs in a Variable.

```
$(idList).hide();
```

Comment: I just tried doing something like what you've written above and I can't seem to get this working, I included what I did at the bottom of the question though if you want to take a look!