# How to sum up all the fields with specific selector name start

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many span fields, which contain the numbers in text format. These  fields have the same first part of name `singleprice-23`, `singleprice-24`, `singleprice-25` etc. How can I sum up all these fields using jQuery ? And how could I do the same for inputs with the same start of name?

Comment: Attribute starts with selector: [`[name^=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: Yup, I know it, but how do I sum up all the values from these fields ?

Comment: Get them from the DOM, iterate over the set and add up the value/parsed text in a variable O.o

Comment: use `$.each([name^="value"])` to add `all selector`'s `val()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery find all ids starting with a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616826/jquery-find-all-ids-starting-with-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- find all the span with id starts with `singleprice`
- iterate on every span and sum its value

See following:

```js
var spans = $('[id^=singleprice]');
var sum = 0;

spans.each(function(index, value){
  sum += +($(value).html());
});

console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="singleprice-23">100</span>
<span id="singleprice-24">200</span>
<span id="singleprice-25">400</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;
$('[name^="singleprice"]').each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).attr('data-single-price');
});
```

This solution assumes that each element which has a name attribute that starts with "singleprice" also has a 'data-single-price' attribute with the value of price. Variable sum is the sum of all these values. If the elements don't have the aforementioned data attribute, then you'd have to write a regex looking at the name value only. I'd say adding a data-single-price attribute is an easier solution, but it depends on your project of course.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all elements that has names starting with "singleprice", get the text/value, trim that, convert that to number and add to the sum variable.

For summing the spans:

```
var sum = 0;
$('[name^="singleprice"]').each(function(){
    sum += +$.trim( $(this).text() );
})
```

For input:

```
var sum = 0;
$('[name^="singleprice"]').each(function(){
    sum += +$.trim( $(this).val() );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.reduce()` in combination with `Array.prototype.map()` can be used to calculate total:

```js
var sum = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('span'), function(o) {
  return parseInt(o.textContent, 10);
}) // <----will return you the array [5,5,5,5,5]
.reduce(function(acc, val) { // <---will iterate over array and add values
  return acc + val;
}, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

```html
<span>5</span>,<span>5</span>,<span>5</span>,<span>5</span>,<span>5</span>
```